# Changing the location of an object on the canvas, using three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to place a number of objects on the canvas, using three js. I'm getting stuck at the point of trying to change the location of the objects. My code is as below:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 1, 1 );
//geometry.position.x = 1;
//geometry.position.y = 1;
//geometry.position.z = 1;
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
//scene.children[1].position.set(0, 0, 0);
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

I've commented out the two different ways I tried to achieve this (both failed). Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set position to a mesh, not a geometry:

```js
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
cube.position.set(1, 1, 1);
scene.add( cube );
```